# TinyMCE in impresspages plugin trouble II

Tags: plugins, impresspages

I replaced **ipTinyMceConfig()** already. It's OK. In the plugin field editor to the richedit is displaying the menus and so on. However when I click in source code menu the source code editor open but disabled for edition. No typing is possible, nothing... Any Idea to solve it? My code replace is like this:

```
    var originalMce =  ipTinyMceConfig;
    var ipTinyMceConfig = function(){
    var customized = originalMce();
    customized.plugins = [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor"
    ];
    console.log('Entered tiny newsletter - New');
    customized.toolbar1 = "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | link image";
    customized.toolbar2 = "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | bullist numlist outdent indent";
    customized.image_advtab = true;
    customized.menubar = true;
    customized.style_formats_merge = true;
    return customized;        
}
```

So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried your code. Are you sure it is disabled? Maybe there is just some kind of CSS overlay that's stands in your way?

Comment: I check it all and looks nothing existing to cause this. But the problem is there whatsoever. In the RichText component outside of the Edit Record environment is all right, however in the plugin Edit Record area, the source code edition of the RichEdit field doesn't work. It looks like disabled control.